# What is the mistake in my calculation of $\int_0^\infty {\cos(ax)\over(x^2+1)^2}dx$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

> What is the mistake in the calculation of $$\int_0^\infty {\cos(ax)\over(x^2+1)^2}dx$$ where $0<a\in\mathbb{R}$?

I know that the question itself has already an answered in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392279/int-0-infty-dfrac-cosaxx2-12dx/392289#392289) but when I comment about questions I rarely get answers so I opned a new question, I hope that ok, sorry in advence if it's not.

**My worng attempt:**
$$ I:=
\int_0^\infty {\cos(ax)\over(x^2+1)^2}={1\over2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty{\cos(ax)\over(x^2+1)^2}=
\\ \int_{C_R}{\cos(ax)\over(x^2+1)^2}
$$
where $C_R$ is the half semicircle centered at the origin with radii $R$ joint with $[-R,R]$.

The above equality holds because $\int_{-R}^R=0$.
$$I=
{1\over2}\cdot 2\pi i\text{Res}({\cos(ax)\over(x^2+1)^2},i)=\\
\pi i({\cos(ax)\over(x^2+i)^2})'|_{z=i}=\\
\pi i\cdot({-a\sin(az)(z+i)^2-2(z+i)\cos(az)\over (z+i)^4})|_{z=i}
=\\ {\pi i\over 16}(a\sin(ai)\cdot 4-4i\cos(ia)=\\
{\pi\over 4}(\cos(ai)+ia\sin(ai))={\pi\over 8}(e^{ai}+e^{-ai}+a(e^{ai}-e^{-ai}))={\pi\over8}(e^{ai}(1+a)+e^{-ai}(1-a))
$$
But the answer should be ${\pi\over 2e}$.

Comment: Note that your answer *must* be wrong, because it has imaginary parts, where the function is only integrated along the real line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$I\neq\displaystyle\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{C_R}\frac{\cos ax\,dx}{(x^2+1)^2}$ because the limit over the *semicircle* doesn't exist (as $\cos ax$ is unbounded there; you have to use $e^{iax}$ for $a>0$ instead).

UPDATE: As noted by @Maxim, the limit still exists (I should have noted it myself as it follows from *your* evaluation). But the rest of above applies.

Comment: Note that the limit does in fact exist, it just isn't zero.